# Dynatable Jquery plugin not setting in table in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I am trying to get a response from Salesforce Analytics API and display as report. Using some sample code help i was able to retrieve the report and display them in table format (as of now i have just hardcoded only first row of data). now i am trying to set dynatable jquery plugin in the table i have created. but for some reason i get an error '$(...).dynatable is not a function'

But I see the table displayed in UI without any formating like as in the attachment [image: UI without formating]

Code as below: I am newbie in UI development so bear with me for any silly mistakes you may see. thanks.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.forcetk)}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"/>
     <apex:includeScript value="!URLFOR($Resource.dynatable,'jquery.dynatable.js')}"/>
     <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.dynatable, 'jquery.dynatable.css')}" />


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

           var reportId = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.reportId}';
            var client = new forcetk.Client();
            client.setSessionToken('{!$Api.Session_ID}');

            // We'll keep the report data around for the life of the page
            var report = null;

            // Run the report synchronously
            client.ajax("/v29.0/analytics/reports/"+reportId+"?includeDetails=true", function(response){
                // Save the report data
                report = response;

                $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(report, null, '    '));



                });                                               

                 $.each(report.factMap, function(index, acg) {

                     if(acg.rows[0] != undefined)
                     {                 
                         console.log(acg.rows[0].dataCells[0].label);
                                                       $('<tbody>').append(                     
                        $('<tr>').append(   
                        $('<td>').text(acg.rows[0].dataCells[0].label),
                        $('<td>').text(acg.rows[0].dataCells[1].label),
                        $('<td>').text(acg.rows[0].dataCells[2].label),


                        )).appendTo('#listdisp');

                 }

          });                

  });



    </script>

<table id='listdisp'>

</table>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#listdisp').dynatable();

        });
</script>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you able to see any error in console when dynatable js got loaded?

Comment: @KiranMachhewar no i see only this error in console $(...).dynatable is not a function

Comment: @Jaguar ** $(...).dynatable is not a function**  error in console then check your static resource